# Groups with identical Charactertabels have a equal sized abilization

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I'd like to prove a question which i found on the internet unfortunatly without a solution.

Let G1 and G2 be two groups with the same character table. Show
that |G1 : [G1, G1]| = |G2 : [G2, G2]|.

Where both Groups are assumed to be finte. Im hard stuck at this one, don't even no how to start i feel like I have to little information given.
So the first question would be what one can deduce from knowing that two Groups have the same charactertabel, it can't be that it implies that they are Isomorphic, (consider $Q_{8}$ and $D_{8}$)
Secondly i'd like to ask for some hints so i can work on the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of one dimensional representations of a group equals the order of its abelianisation. This reult can be found [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Number_of_one-dimensional_representations_equals_order_of_abelianization). The result then follows.

Answer (score 0):

Even better, two finite groups with the same character table even have *isomorphic abelianizations*:

[Does same character table imply isomorphic abelianizations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600377/does-same-character-table-imply-isomorphic-abelianizations)

Comment: I already saw this post but it doesn't help for my question. And the proof structure stated in this post seems way over the top to me there must be a simpler approach

Comment: Yes, there is an easier proof, given already in the post of the duplicate: "the sizes of their abelianizations are equal (in fact equal to the number of linear characters, which can be read off the character table).