# Same character table implies same composition factors

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Groups with the same character table must have the same size and same abelianization,

[Does same character table imply isomorphic abelianizations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600377/does-same-character-table-imply-isomorphic-abelianizations)

although they need not be isomorphic.

Do finite groups with the same complex character table always have the same composition factors?

For example $ D_4 $ and $ Q_8 $ have the same character table and have the same composition factors.

Another more interesting example is that
$$
 AGL(3,2)=2^3 : GL(3,2) = PerfectGroup(1344,1) 
$$
has the same character table as the nonsplit extension
$$
 2^3 \cdot GL(3,2)=PerfectGroup(1344,2) 
$$
and these do indeed have the same composition factors. Notably there is a noncyclic composition factor.

Comment: I can't find a counter-example off the top of my head, but I'm pretty sure it's not true. In general from the character table you can find the lattice of normal subgroups $H$, and you can find the character table of any quotient $G/H$, but in general you *cannot* find the character table of $H$ (you can't even decide if it's abelian). This is not a proof but it does suggest that finding the composition factors is not possible in general.

Comment: In your example, the groups are solvable (actually, $2$-groups), and it is known that you can determine from the character table whether a group is solvable, and obviously in that case all composition factors are trivial to find (they are the cyclic groups with order the prime factors of $|G|$, with the same multiplicities). So in particular if $G$ and $H$ have the same character table and $G$ is solvable, then $G$ and $H$ have the same composition factors. (Your case is even easier: you can tell that $D_4$ and $Q_8$ have the same composition factors just looking at their *order*.)

Comment: @CaptainLama Ok that's a fair point that my example is pretty trivial since all groups of order $ p^n $
 have the same composition factors. I'll add a better example to my question.

Comment: Your notation is wrong. $A:B$ denotes a split extension. Use $A {\cdot} B$ for a nonsplit extension.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you! So the right notation is $ A:B $ is a split extension $ A \cdot B $ is a nonsplit extension and $ n.B $ is a central extension?

Comment: This is known as ATLAS notation, because it was introduced in the ATLAS of Finite Groups, but it has become standard. Yes $A{:}B$ is a split extension and $A{\cdot}B$ (where the $\cdot$ should be a little higher, but I can't work out how to do that) is a nonsplit extension, but $A{.}B$ just denotes an extension of $A$ by $B$ which could be split or nonsplit - either you don't know or you don't care. There is no specific ATLAS notation for central extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theorem 4 of

*Kimmerle, Wolfgang; Sandling, Robert*, [**Group theoretic and group ring theoretic determination of certain Sylow and Hall subgroups and the resolution of a question of R. Brauer**](https://doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1995.1014), J. Algebra 171, No. 2, 329-346 (1995). [ZBL0840.20006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0840.20006).

states that finite groups with the same character table have the same chief factors (and hence the same composition factors).

As one would expect, the proof seems to use the classification of finite simple groups.